# Set Timer Within Function

Tags: javascript, function, object, timer

I have a game object that I want to spawn back (become active) after a certain amount of time. Every time the time has expired, I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'SpawnCounter'
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong? This is part of my object:

```
this.Update = function(){
    //Collisions
    if(this.active){
        if(player.Intersects(this)){
            console.debug("Player Touching Pick Up!");
            if(this.type == "weapon")
                player.weapon = this.subtype;
            this.active = false;
        }
    }
    else{
        //THIS IS THE TIMER
        setTimeout( function(){ this.SpawnCounter(); }, 2000 );
    }
};

this.SpawnCounter = function(){
    this.active = true;
};
```

All this is, is just a game pick up - that re-appears after 2 seconds.

Comment: where is this code getting executed? what's the scope of `this` in execution vs. in setTimeout (`this` actually refers to the window object)?

Comment: …but `this` is not your object in the timed invocation. Use a variable to reference the object, i.e. do `var that = this` outside.

Comment: the 'Update' is getting called via my main game update function "var Update = setInterval(function(){"

Comment: @Bergi well, if `this` refers to the window object when `SpawnCounter` is being defined (which it's unlikely that its being executed globally), then it would be fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try scoping this to another variable...

```
this.Update = function(){
    var that = this;
    //Collisions
    if(this.active){
        if(player.Intersects(this)){
            console.debug("Player Touching Pick Up!");
            if(this.type == "weapon")
                player.weapon = this.subtype;
            this.active = false;
        }
    } else{
        //THIS IS THE TIMER
        setTimeout( function(){ that.SpawnCounter(); }, 2000 );
    }
};

this.SpawnCounter = function(){
    this.active = true;
};
```

Comment: Yep. This is a pretty common practice in JS

Comment: re:'legitimate' -- I believe since there's a reference that this could cause a leak. one could release the reference or it may be better to have a reference to SpawnCounter in a globally accessible object, and then call the method that way?